# How to get photos from one iPad to another

Tags: ipad, icloud

I'll try again at this site although it seems whenever I look for help with a question, I run afoul one rule or another.
I am a volunteer who help seniors with tech problems related to their Apple devices.  I got this from one of them:

We just bought my Mom (102 years) a new iPad replacing one she has used for many years - primarily for email and internet access.  My brother just sent the following note explaining difficulty in loading the new iPad from the old one.  Unfortunately, she remains quarantined in a retirement center.  Your suggestions or leads to reliable blogs would be most welcome:  
    Quote - The good news is that mom has a new seventh generation iPad, and I have been able to reload all her apps and contacts. 
I had to do this manually because her iPad was so old it would not do an AirDrop transfer, and after several hours work, I never could figure out how to load her information up on to iCloud and then download it to the new iPad. 
I know generally how to do this, having done it with new iPhone purchases of my own, but I could not make it work with hers. 
 In any event, what this means is that I have not been able to figure out how to transfer, en masse, the photos and numerous shared website albums that we have all sent her over the years.  When I set up her new iPad, I had to open a new Apple account for her using a new iCloud address. 
So, whatever shared albums and photos that you previously sent her and for which you wish for her to have continued access, you need to reinvite her or resend to her using her email address.  End Quote.

---

With the lady in question quarantined in a nursing home, I don’t know how they got hold of the iPad but they did.
The fact that they had to get her a new Apple ID means that they can’t sync the photos to which they would like to give her access, correct?
I believe they are correct in their surmisal:  "whatever shared albums and photos that you previously sent her and for which you wish for her to have continued access, you need to reinvite her or resend to her using her email address.”
Any suggestions to help out this 102 year old gal would be most welcome.

Comment: iCloud is designed for this sort of thing. Turn on iCloud photos on both iPads and iCloud will copy all of the photos from the old one to the new one. Essentially sync-ing the two. Also making them available online if you are logged into that iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

"I had to open a new Apple account"
That was the mistake.

Nothing on the old iPad is owned by the owner of the new iPad. As far as Apple are concerned, the two accounts are totally & utterly separate.. Your choices now are iCloud sharing, as mentioned, or maybe setting up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/HT201060) or, imo probably the best choice, releasing the new iPad from its current owner & re-assigning it to the right one, as though you were selling it to someone else - [What to do before you sell, give away or trade in your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/HT201351)